# Error when using Math.Net library for Polynomial regression in c sharp

Tags: c#

There is an example for polynomial regression through math.net. But when I copy the example for study. An error happens for QR. The example website is attached as follow:
https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Polynomial_regression#C.23.

The error is as follow:

> Error  1   The type or namespace name 'QR' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    C:\Users\s245275\Desktop\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs 32  13  ConsoleApplication1

Thank you very much!

Comment: can you provide your code where the exception occurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to

1. add a reference to the `MathNet.Numerics` assembly or simply install the `MathNet.Numerics` package if you haven't done so yet and
2. add the appropriate "using" directive at the start of your program

   ```
   using MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Factorization;
   ```

The second step may be omitted if you change

```
QR qr = v.QR();
```

to

```
var qr = v.QR();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. The reference is been added. And if I including the using. A new error happens as follow: Error 1 Using the generic type 'MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Factorization.QR<T>' requires 1 type arguments

Comment: Try changing `QR qr = ...` to `var qr = ...`

Comment: It works now. Thanks a lot. But, I still have a problem with the last output. How could I define the Polyval in the example. Error 1 The name 'Polyval' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Could you please clarify what is the "problem with the last output"?

Comment: for the last three line in the example:             for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
                Console.WriteLine("{0} => {1} diff {2}", x[i], Polyval(p, x[i]), y[i] - Polyval(p, x[i]));
            Console.ReadKey(true);

Comment: The `Polyval` function is not defined anywhere in this C# example. The example appears to be incomplete.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.